# combine data frames using a vector of row indexes

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, dplyr, subset

I have dataframe1, and a vector of row indexes:

```
dataframe1 <-data.frame(time = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5),
                        x = c("light", "light", "light", "dark", "dark", "dark"))
vector <- c(1, 3, 6)
```

I also have dataframe2

```
dataframe2 <- data.frame(time = c(0.6, 1, 1.4, 2, 2.4, 3.2, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5))
```

I want to use values in `dataframe1$time` that correspond to row positions in `vector` to define boundaries in `dataframe2`, such that I end up with this dataset:

```
dataframe2
   time     x
1   0.6 light
2   1.0 light
3   1.4 light
4   2.0 light
5   2.4 light
6   3.2  dark
7   3.5  dark
8   4.0  dark
9   4.5  dark
10  5.0  dark
```

In other words, I want to use row indexes given by `vector` (e.g., 1 & 3) and the corresponding `dataframe1$time` (e.g., 0.5 & 2.5) to find the values in `dataframe2$time` that are >= 0.5 and =< 2.5 (e.g., 0.6, 1, 1.4, 2, 2.4), and then create a new column `x` in `dataframe2` that correspond to `dataframe1$x`.

I do **not** want to combine datasets using `time` as a key value (e.g., cbind).

I hope that was clear. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataframe2$x<-with(dataframe1, unique(x)[findInterval(dataframe2$time, time[vector],all.inside = TRUE)])
dataframe2
   time     x
1   0.6 light
2   1.0 light
3   1.4 light
4   2.0 light
5   2.4 light
6   3.2  dark
7   3.5  dark
8   4.0  dark
9   4.5  dark
10  5.0  dark
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. It appears that your code works on the data frame I've provided. My actual data, however, has more observations, alternating from "light" to "dark". Will your code work?

Comment: I figured it by using `rle(dataframe1$x)$values` instead of `unique()`

Answer (score 1):

We can use a rolling join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataframe1[vector,])[dataframe2, on = .(time = time), roll = -Inf]
```

-output

```
    time     x
 1:  0.6 light
 2:  1.0 light
 3:  1.4 light
 4:  2.0 light
 5:  2.4 light
 6:  3.2  dark
 7:  3.5  dark
 8:  4.0  dark
 9:  4.5  dark
10:  5.0  dark
```